# Implementing BinCounts for alphabetical structures

Tags: list-manipulation, data

Is it possible to implement `BinCounts` for alphabets such that those alphabets which fall into the group `{a,b,c,d}` can be counted as 1, then those in the group `{e,f,g,h}` are another lot "1", and so on? Currently, the `BinCounts` work only for numbers as shown below:

```
BinCounts[{1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2}, {0, 10, 1}]  

 (* {0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0} *)

BinCounts[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, {0, 6, 1}]

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

I guess one way is to link each alphabet to a number, but yet to find a right way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by `are another lot "1"`?

Comment: Something like this? `BinCounts[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g} /. Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> 1] /. 
  Thread[{e, f, g, h} -> 2], {0, 6, 1}]`

Comment: @Belisarius  U got it!, pls shift your comment to ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bins = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}};
vals = {1, 2};
ruls = Flatten@MapThread[Thread[Rule@##] &, {bins, vals}];
set = {a, b, e, e, f};
BinCounts[set /. ruls, {0, 6, 1}]

(* {0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0}*)
```

If you always want  `vals` going from `1` to `Length@bins`, then you can do instead:

```
fun = Function[{r}, Position[bins, r][[1, 1]], Listable];
BinCounts[fun@set, {0, 6, 1}]

(* {0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use the new associations functions.

```
letters = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};    
groups = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}};

asc = Counts[letters]
(* <|a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 1, g -> 1|> *)

Total /@ DeleteMissing /@ Map[asc, groups, {2}]
```

This should be fast assuming that `letters` is large and `groups` is small (since there are only so many letters).

For version 9, I'd build it with `Tally`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The OP asked for a `BinCounts` implementation, which have some additional syntax forms I believe you aren't covering.

Comment: Able to extend @Szabolics to word structures: words = {ate, boy, cat, dog, eat, fat, go, hat}; 
groups = {{ate, boy, cat}, {dog}, {eat, fat}, {go, hat}}; 
asc = Counts[words]
Total /@ DeleteMissing /@ Map[asc, groups, {2}]  with output (* 3,1,2,2 *)

Comment: @belisarius That's not what I thought he was asking.  I though he wanted to count elements belonging to each group.  "binning" makes no sense for objects that have no natural ordering.

Comment: Ok, We understood  the problem differently +1